# Parallel processing with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have built a tool (React front-end and Node.js back end) to accept comma separated strings and then am creating chunks (mini arrays) of 1000 strings each to be passed to my Node.js server for processing. I am using await in server.js so that ordering is maintained. Now this runs fine is only one request is being handled.

As soon as there's more than 1 request, Node.js starts to process the new request and blocks the first one. When code reaches `res.json()`, it gives an error saying - "headers can't be set and all that". It seems like node.js is not able to distinguish between separate requests.

Below is the code from React where I'm making axios.post calls in a loop for each chunk of 100 items. Whenever process is triggered, this function gets called and it splits the string into several chunks and calls axios.post for each one of the chunk.

```
async processArr(data,arr) {
const self = this;
arr = arr.split(',');
var perc = 0;
var chunk = 100;
var start = new Date();
var results = [];
var tempResults = [];
for (var i = 0, j = arr.length; i < j; i += chunk) {
const tempArray = arr.slice(i, i+chunk);
//console.log(tempArray);
const url = config.hostname + 'coupon';
 //const payload = {data};
 const payload = {data: {itemids: tempArray.toString(), userid: this.state.data.userid, data1: this.state.data.data1,
data2: this.state.data.data2, country: this.state.data.country}};
 await axios.post(url, payload)
   .then(res => {
     perc = Math.round(((i + chunk+ 1) / arr.length) * 100).toString();
     this.setState({percentage: perc});
     tempResults = res.data;
     tempResults.map(function(item, index) {
       //console.log(item)
       results.push({item})
     }.bind(this))
   })
}
```

On the Node side, I am using recursion to go through each of the items in the chunk individually. I have to make minimum 2 or maximum 3 API calls for each item in chunk. That code is a bit too large to show.

Now in my server.js, I have this which calls _getToken method from a different file and uses the response from that to call _findItemDetailsArray (again in a different file). When I have the final array of items in resultObjArrayFailedItemsOnly, I am calling startProcess with argument 0. This starts a recursive loop to process each item of the array resultObjArrayFailedItemsOnly and sends res.json back when done.

```
try {
  commonFunctions._getToken().then(resToken => {
    token = resToken;
    if (itemids) {
      var arrItemIds = itemids.split(',');
      //console.log('_findItemDetailsArray called with ' + arrItemIds.length + ' items');
      commonFunctions._findItemDetailsArray(arrItemIds, 'irc').then(data => {
        //console.log('_findItemDetailsArray sent a response');
        xml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(data.res);
        var matchCount = parseInt(xml.getElementsByTagName('soapenv')[2].children[0].children[4].children[0].value);
        if (matchCount > 0) {
          for (i = 5; i < matchCount + 5; i++) {
            resultObjArrayPassedItemsOnly.push(xml.getElementsByTagName('soapenv')[2].children[0].children[i].children[5].children[0].value);
            resultObjArrayPassed.push({
              cur: xml.getElementsByTagName('soapenv')[2].children[0].children[i].children[1].children[0].attributes.currencyId,
              pc: xml.getElementsByTagName('soapenv')[2].children[0].children[i].children[1].children[0].value,
              iepi: xml.getElementsByTagName('soapenv')[2].children[0].children[i].children[4].children[0].value,
              si: xml.getElementsByTagName('soapenv')[2].children[0].children[i].children[3].children[0].value,
              ii: xml.getElementsByTagName('soapenv')[2].children[0].children[i].children[5].children[0].value
            });
          }
          resultObjArrayFailedItemsOnly = arrItemIds.filter(item => !resultObjArrayPassedItemsOnly.includes(item));
        }
        else {
          Array.prototype.push.apply(resultObjArrayFailedItemsOnly, arrItemIds);
        }
      })
        .then(function () {
          console.log('start process called');
          startProcess(0);
        })
    }
  })
}
catch (err) {
  console.log(err.stack);
}
```

Definition of _getToken -

```
_getToken: async function () {
    var url = "some url";
    try {
        const resToken = await axios.get(url);
        return resToken.data.access_token;
    }
    catch (err) {
        throw err;
    }
}
```

Definition of __findItemDetailsArray is similar. It also uses await to process items in order.

Now, the definition of startProcess -

```
startProcess = (i) => {
      if (i >= resultObjArrayPassedItemsOnly.length) {
        //when full array is processed, res.json
        res.json(outputObjectArray);
        return;
      }
            else {
        console.log(i);
        if (iepi.toLowerCase() === 'yes') {
            //make a call to a function similar _getToken
            _getData(args1, args2).
            then(res => {
                //do something
            }).
            then(function() {
                startProcess(i+1);
            })
        }
        else {
            //similar to what is being done in if..
            //do something and call startProcess with an incremented value
        }
        //console.log('output object array: ' + outputObjectArray);
        //setTimeout(startProcess, 0, (parseInt(i) + 1));
      }
}
```

The error occurs at the line where I have res.json(outputObjectArray). As soon as I start a second instance using a new tab, node starts to process that and instantly errors out or just processes the second string of items without showing any output and forgets to come back to the first request.

I know for sure that this is not how Node is supposed to work but I just don't understand what's the issue here. Is it the recursive function?

Comment: You can use `child-process`  and job queue like `kue` to separate jobs

Comment: it will be blocking if you are using synchronous operations which is what it sounds like even though you said you are using await (which works with async). using child processes will help but if you have an issue after 1 request this will not be the main solution, as it will block after all cores are used.

Comment: I doubt we can help you without seeing your request processing code.  It sounds like you just have some mistakes in that code.

Comment: Thanks guys for your comments. Hey @jfriend00 - I have added the React side of the code. Please let me know if you guys want to have a look at Node side too. In the meanwhile I will have a look at child-process.

Comment: I thought the main problem was when you said this: ***"headers can't be set and all that". It seems like node.js is not able to distinguish between separate requests***.  To help you with that, we need to see the code for that node.js request handler.

Comment: Yep that is the issue. I have added some more code as you asked - @jfriend00. Let me know if you want to look at some other function.

Comment: Hey @Noface, can you have a look at this again. I have added some code.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Thanks @halfer. Didn't know about this.

Comment: This code is difficult to reason about so I don't have an answer to fix your code. It seems unecessary to do all of this when there are already csv parsers https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parse https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-csv https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv - what makes your tool different? Once you fully specify the actual thing you are trying to do, which is not parallel processing, but make your code work for more than 1 request, then we can help.

Comment: Thanks @Noface for your reply. I have built this tool to be used internally within the company. The tool accepts a item numbers separated by comma up to 50k. Now to keep the browser alive, I am chunking the string into arrays of 1000 items each and calling server.js for each of the small arrays. When node.js finishes the process, response is sent back using res.json and processing of 2nd chunk starts. Now while this happens, if one more session is initiated, node.js starts processing that and it fails to finish either of them. Sometimes I get "headers can't be set" error because of res.json.

Comment: you should instead use Streams to deal with large amounts of data, which handles chunking for you, in combination with a csv parser. https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream

Comment: could you paste some input data and wanted output data e.g. input `10,12,3,154,133` from a text file... and output '[10,12,3,154,133]` as a JSON array ?

Comment: I'd back the streams and if you couple those with [scramjet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet) you'll be able to offload your work into multiple threads to avoid blocking.

Comment: Thanks @Noface. I will have a look into these libraries. The input would be as you mentioned.. 127465365, 785645657567, 678678786786, 7678678768 from a text area in a form. Output would be an Object Array containing metadata for each of these IDs after making 2-3 API calls for each item one after another - [{'Success', '$123', '$34.90', 'abcd', 'abcd'}, {...}, {...} .. ] Since these API calls take too long, I am chunking the input and calling res.json for each chunk to keep the browser (ReactJS) alive otherwise I'm getting 502 error.